# Python Setuptools/setup.py Install Upstart Configuration

Tags: python, setuptools, egg, upstart

Is there an elegant way to have setuptools deposit and install an Upstart configuration, or should I just do it from a custom pre-hook (cmdclass)?

Can Setuptools be used to install files in arbitrary locations, in general?

Thank you.

Dustin

Comment: System package manager, configuration manager, or deployment scripts should be responsible for that, not setup.py even if you can coerce it into doing it (imo)

Comment: And yet, to use a system package manager would mean that I could no longer list the project among Python packages in PyPI, nor use its dependency management. If 1) the module requires itself to be made a service, 2) it is a common need of packages (of any type, whether it's Python, C, etc..), and 3) many/most system services are written in Python, then why build eggs in such a way as to either a) require developers to copy and paste boilerplate Upstart code into their setup.py file, or b) require users to establish the service by hand? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: almost every sentence in your comment is wrong. Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Look at projects that are similar to yours and see how they organize distribution/deployment/configuration. Ask specific questions if you are not satisfied with the solutions.

Comment: What I interpreted your original response as, was to create more steps for the user to do something that was often automated. I also cited that it would make sense to have the installation utility do this, as it already does for executable scripts declared via the "scripts" config parameter, -rather- than have the developer always implement the same extra stuff, every time they needed to deploy a service with a project. Rather than being offensive and indignant, just reply, man.